# Issue in gradle

Tags: flutter

I've first had a problem about my minSDk version so i changed to 26, so a lot of issues started to appear, about cloud_firestore, video_player version, so i've downgraded the version and the error changed, and now i've started having package errors like "txt.something it's missing", so i've add this code :
And i also changed my compile sdkVersion to 28

```
   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
```

and now it's giving me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
    > Android dependency 'androidx.fragment:fragment' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.1.0-alpha04) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

So i've add: in my gradle, but started giving me a loop of this errors, of diferent libraries that has different versions

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'androidx.fragment:fragment:v4:1.1.0-alpha04'
}
```

}

I've also tried to set my com.google.gms:google-services to 3.2.1, add the code :

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add in my gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {

        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.gacitua.catilholi.goodstart"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```